# Visual c++ doesn't have sys/wait.h

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have downloaded the timezone database library and am trying to compile it under windows to a DLL. When I do this, I get messages like:

```
1>c:\javatools\tzinfo\src\private.h(97): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/wait.h': No such file or directory
```

and, of course, sys/wait.h is not ANSI C, which is the issue. I seem to recall windows have some near file names to this. Can I get an assist here?

Thanks.

Comment: What function do you want to call?

Comment: What library? How do you compile it? Does it support MSVC at all? If it does most likely you don't build it well. In any case `sys/wait.h` is POSIX header... Don't expect it to be present on Windows.

Comment: No idea. included in an include and none of it my code. I poked around and didn't see anything.

Comment: Take the include out and see what happens!!

Comment: Maybe remove the include of those headers and see what the code is attempting to call?

Comment: Then I suggest you define an empty header to get past the missing file error and then you will see which function calls pose a problem.

Comment: The code had a #ifdef, which I'm assuming is for compiling under windows. I defined it as zero instead of 1 and the error disappeared. Many more errors to go. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the `wait()` equivalent of MSVS, look no further than [WaitForSingleObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: What is the Windows equivalent of `wait(NULL)`?

Answer (score 6):

`fork()`, `wait()` and `waitpid()` are defined by the POSIX standard, and Windows is not POSIX-compliant.

In order to have POSIX compliance under Windows, you should compile under Cygwin.

The analogous WinAPI functions are `CreateProcess` and `GetProcessExitCode`.

Comment: GetProcessExitCode is non-blocking, and is not the same as wait() at all.