# Atom.io missing sys/wait.h or allow fork()

Tags: c, concurrency, atom-editor

I am attempting to learn how to concurrently run algorithms in c using fork(). It appears that atom.io won't add sys/wait.h when compiling, but when my exact same code is running on a school server it will compile just fine. Is there a way to add additional header files to atom and allow for it to use fork and wait? Im running the program on windows 10, but the school database uses unix, would that effect the header files?

This is the exact code I am running for a test with fibonacci and is compiled using GCC minGW

I get the simple error of sys/wait.h no such file or directory and it appears that if I comment out sys/wait , "waitpid is no longer declared in this scope"and "Fork was not declared in this scope"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{

int a=0, b=1, n=a+b,i;

printf("Enter the number of a Fibonacci Sequence:\n");
scanf("%d", &i);

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    printf("Child Fibonacci\n");
    printf("0 %d ",n);
    while (i>0) {
        n=a+b;
        printf("%d ", n);
        a=b;
        b=n;
        i--;
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("\nChild ends\n");
    }
 }
}
    else
    {
    printf("Parent is waiting for child to complete...\n");
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    printf("Parent ends\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Also, if you are learning C, do not tag a question with the [tag:c++] tag (as well, or instead); it will get you down-votes rather quickly.  If a header cannot be found, it often means there's an installation problem of some sort. Which platform are you on? Which compiler are you using? Is it only `<sys/wait.h>` that's missing, or are other headers missing too? It's fundamental; normally, on Unix-like systems, if you have, for example, `<stdio.h>`, you'll also have `<sys/wait.h>`, especially if it's got `<sys/types.h>`.

Comment: Windows, linux or mac?

Comment: Please add the information to the question (you can always edit your own questions), and then delete the comment.  Which C compiler are you using on Windows 10?  MS Visual Studio, or MinGW, or Cygwin, or something else?  (Add the answer to this to the question too, please.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the include directory of MinGW if you're under Windows or GNU linux and look for the file, btw this question is very similar to this: [Visual c++ doesn't have sys/wait.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841187/visual-c-doesnt-have-sys-wait-h)